# Make only some keyframes linear

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I know you can make keyframes interpolation linear, constant, or Bezier, but this affects all of them.  How can I do this to just a few without dragging the handles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the keyframes in the graph editor and press <kbd>T</kbd>*> Linear*. This will only affect the selected keyframes:

[image]